# Composition of continuous and $L^p$ function is in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a finite measure space, $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that:

$$\exists K\geq 0 : |g(t)|\leq K|t| \text{ for all } t\in\mathbb{R} \text{ such that } |t|\geq K$$

If $f\in L^p$ ($f:X\to\mathbb{R}$), show that $(g\circ f)\in L^p$.

The easy part is to see the case $|f(x)|\geq K$, in fact, define $A:=\{x\in X: |f(x)|\geq K\}$, then:

$$\int_{A}|g\circ f|^pd\mu\leq\int K^p|f|^pd\mu=K^p\int|f|^pd\mu<\infty$$

Now for $A^c=\{x\in X: |f(x)|< K\}$ I don't know how to prove that $(g\circ f)\in L^p$. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g$ is continuous, it is bounded on $|t|\leq K$, i.e., there exists $M>0$ such that $|g(t)|\leq M$ for all $|t|\leq K$. Hence on $A^c$, where $|f(x)|<K$, we have
$$|(g\circ f)(x)|\leq M,$$
so
$$\int_{A^c}|g\circ f|^pd\mu\leq\int_{A^c}M^pd\mu\leq M^p\mu(X)<\infty,$$
where $\mu(X)<\infty$ follows from the assumption that $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a finite measure space.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but the fact of not having used that space is of finite measure makes me noise :/

Comment: @JadMON2k1 The conclusion will be false if the sapce is not of finite measure. For example, $f\equiv0$ and $g(0)\neq 0$, in which case $g\circ f$ will be a non-zero constant, who doesn't belong to any $L^p$ sapces with $p<\infty$.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous but does not satisfy that other condition $(\exists K\geq 0:|g(t)|\leq K|t|)$, then $(g\circ f)$ is not in $L^p$? I think it's obvious because otherwise the problem wouldn't impose that condition, but the truth is I can't think of an example.

Comment: @JadMON2k1 Example: Let $X=(0,1)$ with the usual Lebesgue measure, and $f(x)=x^{-1/2}\in L^1(0,1)$. If $g(t)=t^2$, then $g\circ f(x)=x^{-1}\notin L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!